# Call Set-Location from within a cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm creating a cmdlet for PowerShell and I need to be able to call `Set-Location` (aka `cd`) from within a the cmdlet. I would do it like this

```
var setLocation = new Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand();
setLocation.Path = path;
setLocation.Invoke();
```

except that it gives me an error that says `You cannot invoke a cmdlet that derrives from PSCmdlet`. I'd like to use `Set-Location`, but I'd be happy with just simply changing the directory of the shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best answer I could find was to use `InvokeScript` to change directory:

```
InvokeCommand.InvokeScript(string.Format("Set-Location {0}", fullPath));
```

It's possible that there's a "more C#" way to do this, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit older but here is a slightly nicer solution:

The class [PathIntrinsics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pathintrinsics) contains the method [SetLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pathintrinsics.setlocation).

To manipulate the path of the current session, you can access the [PathIntrinsics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pathintrinsics) via the [SessionState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.sessionstate) using the [Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.sessionstate.path) property.

long story short:

```
SessionState.Path.SetLocation("C:/some/path");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to derive from CMDLET not PSCMDLET.

Answer (score -1):

Simply using Set-Location inside the script should do the work.

So for example:

```
# Script.ps1
CD ~
Get-Location
Set-Location c:\Windows
Get-location
```

Once the script finishes, try Get-Location again!

Comment: I'm in a cmdlet, not a script

Answer (score -1):

If I use Set-Location in a script, I usually like to first use Push-Location to store the current location and then at the end of my script I can use Pop-Location to return the user to where they were.

```
Push-Location $PWD
Set-Location $somewhere
#script body
Pop-Location
```

Unless of course, the intention of the script is to change directories for the user.

Comment: Why not? If I'm using a script that gives me no benefit from changing my location, it only changes location to make the script easier to write, it would annoy me if I wasn't in my starting location after the script ran. For example, if you ran dir 'c:\program files' you wouldn't expect that after running that your location was changed to c:\program files would you?